# Meaning of "whole" in this TCL foreach loop (regex)

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to understand what the "whole" keyword does in the foreach loop below. I wrote a regex expression to find numbers between a | and ) in a text. See the output below when I run the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set text "A(1|1) B(1|3) C(1|6)"

#regex to find numbers between | and )
set pattern {\|([0-9]+)\)}  
                         
set matches [regexp -all -inline $pattern $text]

foreach {whole num} $matches {
        puts $num
}

puts "---"

foreach num $matches {
        puts $num
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
6
---
|1)
1
|3)
3
|6)
6
```

The first loop output is desired, but why is the second loop showing |1),|3), when I remove the "whole" keyword?

Comment: Have you inspected what's in the $matches list variable?

Comment: `whole` is a variable name, btw, not a keyword (Which tcl doesn't really have if you want to be nitpicky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've been told, `regexp -all -inline` produces a list of things it has matched, where that list has several entries per match (first is the full match, subsequent entries are per capturing subexpression); its actual result here is `|1) 1 |3) 3 |6) 6`. What's going on with the `foreach` with the `whole`?

Well, the word `whole` is not special at all. It's just a variable name. The general form of that type of `foreach` is:

> **foreach** *listOfVariableNames* *listToIterateOver* *body*

The `{whole num}` is a list of two variable names, so each iteration through `$matches` we pull off two elements of the list and assign them to each of the variables. If the body had instead been:

```
puts "whole = '$whole' num = '$num'"
```

The output would have been:

```
whole = '|1)' num = '1'
whole = '|3)' num = '3'
whole = '|6)' num = '6'
```

As you're actually not otherwise using `whole`, the effect is to ignore the whole-matches and just use the sub-expression matches. This is a fairly common pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression has one subgroup which is  `([0-9]+)`.
So, while applied with `-inline`, it will return a list containing the whole match and the 1st subgroup.

The result is not just limited with 1st subgroup. It is based on how many subgroups you are supplying to the expression. For e.g.

```
% regexp -inline {\d[a-z][A-Z]} "0bX"; # No subgroups
0bX
% regexp -inline {\d[a-z]([A-Z])} "0bX"; # subgroup only for upper-case letters
0bX X
% regexp -inline {\d([a-z])[A-Z]} "0bX"; # subgroup only for lower-case letters
0bX b
% regexp -inline {(\d)[a-z][A-Z]} "0bX"; # subgroup only for digits
0bX 0
% regexp -inline {(\d[a-z])[A-Z]} "0bX"; # subgroup only for digit-lower-case combination
0bX 0b
% regexp -inline {(\d[a-z])([A-Z])} "0bX"; # 1st subgroup is for digit-lower-case  and 2nd subgroup is for upper-case letter
0bX 0b X
% regexp -inline {(\d)([a-z])([A-Z])} "0bX"# 1st subgroup is for digit and 2nd subgroup is for lower-case letter and 3rd subgroup is for upper-case letter
0bX 0 b X
%
```

Note that in all of these results, the whole match (which is the complete match) is always provided at first and then the subsequent `n` subgroup matches.

This will applicable to `-all` flag as well. So, the process is repeated for all matches.

Now, if we apply this logic to your code, we get the following

```
# 1st whole match, 1st whole match's 1st subgroup, 2nd whole match, 2nd match's 1st subgroup and so on    
% set matches [regexp -all -inline $pattern $text];
|1) 1 |3) 3 |6) 6
%
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0U0R/1/)